# Mysql&MSAccess: insert into table which have an incremented field

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, sqlexception

I am sorry if there is a duplicate but I tried all ways still I can't do the insertion.

I have a table with only two fields ( ID , Name ) 
When I run this SQL code it must be insert a new record and increment the `ID` field automatically
because it's auto increment  but unfortunately don't work . 
See the trail and errors :

**MYSQL :**

1. `PreparedStatement pr = con.prepareStatement("insert into names(name) values(?)");
    pr.setString(2,"Azad");`

   ***java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number    of parameters, which is 1).***
2. `insert into names(id,name) values(?,?)`

   ***java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1***

**MS Access :**

1. `insert into names(name) values(?)`

***java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1***

1. `insert into names(id,name) values (?,?)`

***java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect***

What's the reason of those errors ? and how to solve it ?

Thanks for suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change pr.setString(2,"Azad"); to pr.setString(1,"Azad");

The first parameter is related to the position of the ? in the prepared statement, not the column index in the table.

java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1. This is down to the fact that you have specified two parameters for the query. But have only specified one value, for the second parameter. If "ID" is an auto incremented column then you don't need to pass in a value. If its not then

pr.setString(1,IDVALUE);

pr.setString(2,"Azad");