# Issue with AUTO_INCREMENT field in insert statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert

i have a database table whose primary key is an auto incremented value

how do i insert data into this table, without inserting this value, which is supposed to update on its own

this is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
Users(lastName CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
userID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
phone CHAR(15),
email CHAR(50),
address CHAR(100),
authLevel INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
FOREIGN KEY(authLevel) REFERENCES Authorizations (authLevel),
login CHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
firstName CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (userID),password CHAR(30) NOT NULL);
```

this is my insert statement:

```
(firstName,lastName,login,password,address,email) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

and this is the exception i get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'userID' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at com.database.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Comment: The answer is accepted, but let me ask, you're using `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: yes. 
and this is to make the answer longer

Comment: Did you tried `preparedStatement.setString(1,"firstName");`..... ?

Comment: that is exactly what i did , and this is the result i received....  statement.setString(editableColumns.indexOf(KEY_FIRST_NAME)+1,firstName);
  statement.setString(editableColumns.indexOf(KEY_LAST_NAME)+1, lastName);
  statement.setString(editableColumns.indexOf(KEY_LOGIN)+1, login);
  statement.setString(editableColumns.indexOf(KEY_PASSWORD)+1, password);
  statement.setString(editableColumns.indexOf(KEY_ADDRESS)+1, address);
  statement.setString(editableColumns.indexOf(KEY_EMAIL)+1, email);
  statement.setString(editableColumns.indexOf(KEY_PHONE)+1, phone);

Comment: Make sure `editibleCol......` starts from `1`, [Read this question, I had the same problem as you once.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256977/mysqlmsaccess-insert-into-table-which-have-an-incremented-field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised it doesn't work as is, but passing null or 0 as the value for userID should make it work.

Comment: it was strange to me as well, as i've used it on other platforms and passing no value at all, usually did the trick, this is the first time i saw this in java... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.I solved the problem by adding DEFAULT 0 at auto incremented column definition.